# TensorFlow and KenLM

Tags: tensorflow, speech-recognition, kenlm

How does one use `KenLM` with `tensorflow` as decoder?
I know about `tensorflow-with-kenlm` tf fork, but it is based on 1.1 tf version which doesn't have many important features for my project.